# Using Ajax POST and PHP unlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unlink

I have this annoying problem that wont seem to be solved.
The base is a dynamic table which loads via JQuery to **client.php** showing data from MySQL database via **getdata.php**. In this data which appears in **client.php** i have a buttonlink from which I remove the selected row from the database and at the same time unliks two images with the same name but from two different directories.

It all works if i put the image-name in by hand on the button , but not when i use `$row['photo']`. 
The wierd thing is if I use `$row['photo']` and echo the value of `photo` in the javascript-function it displays the correct name.

**getdata.php**

```
$output_string .= '<td><input type=button id="testbtn" value="'.$movedatabutton1.'" onClick=movedata("'.$selectedList.'","'.$movedatadestination1.'","'.$row['id'].'","'.$row['photo'].'");></td>';
```

**client.php**

```
    function movedata(from,to,id,photo) {
    $.post('movedata.php', { from: from, to: to, id: id, photo: photo },
        function(output) {
            $('#topDivLeft').html(output).show();
            alert(photo);
        });
    }
```

**movedata.php**

```
$from = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["from"]);
$to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["to"]);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id"]);
$photo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["photo"]);
$photoPath = "upload/".$photo;
$thumbPath = "uploadthumb/".$photo;

if ($to == "removePermanently") {
// ta bort ansökan permanent
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM $from WHERE id = $id")
    or die(mysql_error()); 

// stäng bilderna om de är öppna    
$fp = fopen($photoPath, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($fp);
$ft = fopen($thumbPath, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ft);

// ta bort bilderna från servern
if (is_writable("$photoPath")) unlink("$photoPath");
if (is_writable("$thumbPath")) unlink("$thumbPath");
} else {
// flytta ansökan
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $to (id, Tid, Fornamn, Efternamn, Gata, Postnr, Postort, Telefon, Epost, Projektplats, Projekttyp, Nuvarande, Onskemal, Budget, Programledare, photo, Kommentar) SELECT id, Tid, Fornamn, Efternamn, Gata, Postnr, Postort, Telefon, Epost, Projektplats, Projekttyp, Nuvarande, Onskemal, Budget, Programledare, photo, Kommentar from $from WHERE id = $id") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM $from WHERE id = $id")
    or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Would be greatful for any help!

Comment: Are you sure that `upload` and `uploadthumb` directories are in the same directory as `movedata.php` is?

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($photoPath, $thumbPath);`? Also, don't use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$photo` if it's not going into MySQL. But I would definitely do something to sanitize that. What if I passed in `../*` (or something worse) for the `photo` parameter?

Comment: They are, and as I said - if I change `$row['photo']` to "image_name.jpg" it works.

Comment: @Travesty3 when I do the var_dump and write in "hej.jpg" instead of `$row['photo']` I get `string(14) "upload/hej.jpg" string(19) "uploadthumb/hej.jpg" null` and when I do it with `$row['photo']` I get `string(7) "upload/" string(12) "uploadthumb/" null`, so it seems the value doesnt tag along.

Comment: Sounds like `$row['photo']` is not being populated correctly. Where is the code that does that? Also, I would really advise against adding your `onClick` event inline. It looks like you are using jQuery, so in your head, you should just do `$(document).on('ready', function() { $('#testbtn').on('click', function() { movedata(...); }); });`

Comment: @Travesty3 you were right and thanks to your `var_dump` I found the problem. And about the not having `onClick` - how can I use your method when the links are different for every row?

Comment: I would have to see all of your code in order to refactor it. I can pretty much guarantee that there is a better solution that does not use inline JavaScript, but that's outside the scope of this question. Just a general rule of thumb, avoid inline JavaScript. If you think you need to use it, that's usually a hint that you could refactor your code for a better solution.